# How to find out which HTML element has been touched in a webview?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to find out which element has been clicked on when the user touches the contents of an `Android.Webkit.WebView`, quite independently of what the type of the HTML element is.

My approach so far was to use the Touch event and perform a hit test like such:

```
private void WebView_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
{
    var hitTest = webView.GetHitTestResult();
    var type = hitTest.Type;
    var element = hitTest.Extra;
    // Determine what todo based on type and element
}
```

However, when I click for instance on a `<button>` element, the event is fired, but the hit test yields no results, i.e., type and element are empty. Maybe the hit test was not yet done? Do I need to call `GetHitRect`?

Comment: GetHitTestResult only works with certain known types of elements like anchor, img etc. refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getHitTestResult()
What are your requirements specifically? that would help to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Nandy: Thanks, good to know. I refined the question appropriately. In my test scenario, I tried with a `<button>` element. I guess those will be the most important, but the solution should be generic in that regard, ideally.

Answer (score 1):

We can detect following HTML elements as per Android API Document.

```
    int     ANCHOR_TYPE     HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag
    int     EDIT_TEXT_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an edit text area
    int     EMAIL_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an email address
    int     GEO_TYPE    HitTestResult for hitting a map address
    int     IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE   HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag which contains HTML::img
    int     IMAGE_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an HTML::img tag
    int     PHONE_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting a phone number
    int     SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE     HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag with src=http
    int     SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE   HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag with src=http + HTML::img
    int     UNKNOWN_TYPE    Default HitTestResult, where the target is unknown
```

Comment: I understood this enumeration as something giving you an extra hint what kind of element was processed, but is the hit test functionality limited to these types?